Does it make sense to have 2 mandatory headers in a REST API?
Context:
I'm building a REST API where all our endpoints are protected. The consumer of the API is a hotel. Each hotel has a unique API key. The hotel has guests. Each guest has a unique ID within that hotel. It is the hotel's responsibility to determine a unique ID for each of their users.
When the client app consumes our API, we use both the API token and the unique user id to determine:

Whether or not hotel has access to our services (api_key)
Who is the guest inside that hotel so we know what data to present to them (unique_user_id)

That makes both api_key, and unique_user_id mandatory fields.
Problem:
I've started implementing this rules and documentation using swagger, but:

Swagger doesn't seem to be designed to allow for 2 mandatory headers
The framework i'm using (tsoa) doesn't make that task easy and it seems a bit hacky to have 2 mandatory headers

So my question is:
Is having 2 mandatory headers a good idea in the first place ?
Maybe unique_user_id should be in the payload (for POST) and url params (GET) instead?
It just seemed cleaner to have everything in the headers since they are both mandatory anyway but I'm wondering if there is any best practices in that regard. What are your thoughts?

while I support about token, I also not see any problem to mark 2 in-path items,  as required, are you use OpenApi 3.0 or 2 ? Also if not use in-path what a problem to set it in required list for request body property ?

I would recommend you consider using a token authentication.

In this schema you use one header (Authorization: Bearer token).
In the JWT (Json Web Token) you can put all the necessary information.
And using OAuth 2.0, you don't have to worry about the information inside the token being tampered with.

